# Probability for winning $\$5$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

How to do this probability?

Do I need to find the probability for first two times that I can not win $\$5$, then the probability to win $\$5$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First consider which sequences of two die rolls result in a net profit of more than $5. Find the probability of these scenarios and sum them to find the total probability.

Comment: Just list which of the 36 possible combinations of two die rolls give a profit of at least \$5. Note that at least one of the two must be a six - otherwise you'll never reach \$5, so there aren't too many possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

hint: there are 36 different outcomes. Find all the winning ones (for example, if the first die shows 1 you will never manage to achieve this). In this cases, direct observation is the best strategy.

Comment: Can I have 3, 4,5 in the first and 2nd through so I can win $\$ 5$ in the third attempts?

Comment: the problem states that you have just two throws at disposal. Again: start by eliminating all first throws which cannot let you arrive at the goal. Each remaining throw has probability 1/6 of happening: which are the winning second throws?